# Does calling method in the argument list of another method is a good practice in Java?

Tags: java

Is it a *good* practice to call a method from another method's parameter list?

```
public String processRequestBasedOnCondition(MyObject obj) {
   return executeRequest(frameRequestObject(obj));
}

public String executeRequest(RequestObject rqObject){
   return rqObject.execute();
}
```

1. Can I hold the return value of `frameRequestObject(obj)` in a variable and pass it as argument to the `executeRequest()?` Which is the best practice in this case?
2. Is it a good practice to return the value like "return `rqObject.execute();`" ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes you can

   ```
   public String processRequestBasedOnCondition(MyObject obj) {
       RequestObject requestObject = frameRequestObject(obj);
       return executeRequest(requestObject);
   }
   ```
2. More preference than practice.

Some could argue that assigning the call to a variable is more readable. Personally I would simply `return rqObject.execute()` as it is readable enough as it is.

Answer (score 0):

`Can I hold the return value of frameRequestObject(obj) in a variable and pass it as argument to the executeRequest()? Which is the best practice in this case?`

**Yes** ,you can.but for better readability first capture the output of method and then pass it to other method.

`is it a good practice to return the value like "return rqObject.execute()`

Here also better readability of code matters but yes you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in this case you should be fine as you are.

Programming readable code is important. In this case using something such as `return executeRequest(frameRequestObject(obj));` is still pretty much readable.

Things start getting messy when you have something like so:  `return executeRequest(foo.getBar().getValue().frameRequestObject(obj));`

Code like above should be avoided. This is why most of the time it is recommended to always break things down.

Answer (score 0):

It is in effect **functional** style (which is *fine*).

Answer (score 0):

1. As long as the code stays readable, no problem. If you end up with 10 method invocations in a single line of code being 200 characters long, it's not acceptable anymore
2. Yes. Storing the result of the invocation in a local variable and returning the local variable doesn't serve any real purpose. It can help for debugging, but returning the result directly is OK. If an additional variable is needed for debugging, you can still add it at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

Its frankly more **both** are about the **Preference than practice.**

**1.**

```
RequestObject reqObj = frameRequestObject(obj);
   return executeRequest(reqObj);
```

**2.**
   For a newbie something like this return rqObject.execute(), can be confusing. **Yet
   its a cleaner way to do it... I would prefer this.**